# Evaluating a Text Expression based on Values from another table

Tags: text, expression

I have two tables:

Tbl1:

```
MetricID    Date    Value   
SC-1a    2/27/2017  883     
SC-1b    2/27/2017  1025    
SC-2a    2/27/2017  734     
SC-2b    2/27/2017  291     
SC-2c    2/27/2017  0   
SC-2d    2/27/2017  19  
SC-2e    2/27/2017  0   
SC-2f    2/27/2017  58  
SC-2g    2/27/2017  1   
SC-2h    2/27/2017  0   
SC-2i    2/27/2017  0
```

Tbl2:

```
MetricID    MetricCalc
SC-1        SC-1a / SC-1b
SC-2       ((SC-2a + SC-2b + SC-2c) - (SC-2d + SC-2e + SC-2f + SC-2g + SC-2h + SC-2i)) / (SC-2a + SC-2b + SC-2c)
```

Is it possible to evaluate the expression in Tbl2 with corresponding values in Tbl1 for specific dates?

For example: For the date 2/27/2017
SC-1a / SC-1b would evaluate to 883/1025 = 0.8614 and
((SC-2a + SC-2b + SC-2c) - (SC-2d + SC-2e + SC-2f + SC-2g + SC-2h + SC-2i)) / (SC-2a + SC-2b + SC-2c) would evaluate to ((734+291+0) - (19+0+58+1+0+0)) / (734+291+0) = 0.9239

Searching on Google provided links dealing with evaluating mathematical expressions that had direct numbers in them. In this case, text in the expression needs to be replaced by corresponding numbers and then evaluated. I'm very new to SQL and any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks for your assistance.

Question also posted at https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1861974/Evaluating-a-Text-Expression-based-on-Values-from-another-table

Answer (score 0):

Answer I made on SSC, but posted here as OP didn't respond to consumable DDL and Sample data request.:

```
CREATE TABLE #Metrics (MetricID VARCHAR(5),
                       MetricDate DATE,
                       MetricValue INT);

CREATE TABLE #Calculations (CalculationID VARCHAR(4), --These shouldn't have the same name in both tables as they are not the same thing
                            Calculation VARCHAR(500));
GO
INSERT INTO #Metrics
VALUES
('SC-1a','20170227',883),     
('SC-1b','20170227',1025),
('SC-2a','20170227',734),    
('SC-2b','20170227',291),   
('SC-2c','20170227',0),
('SC-2d','20170227',19),  
('SC-2e','20170227',0),   
('SC-2f','20170227',58),  
('SC-2g','20170227',1),   
('SC-2h','20170227',0),   
('SC-2i','20170227',0);

INSERT INTO #Calculations
VALUES
('SC-1','SC-1a / SC-1b'),
('SC-2', '((SC-2a + SC-2b + SC-2c) - (SC-2d + SC-2e + SC-2f + SC-2g + SC-2h + SC-2i)) / (SC-2a + SC-2b + SC-2c)');
GO

SELECT CalculationID, Calculation, 1 AS RN
FROM #Calculations C
     LEFT JOIN #Metrics M ON PATINDEX('%' + M.MetricID + '%', C.Calculation) > 0
WHERE C.CalculationID = 'SC-1'

GO
DECLARE @DATE DATE = '27-Feb-2017';

WITH Replacements AS (
    SELECT CalculationID, Calculation, Calculation As CastCalculation, 1 AS RN
    FROM #Calculations C
    --WHERE C.CalculationID = 'SC-1'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT R.CalculationID,
           CAST(REPLACE(R.Calculation, M.MetricID, CAST(M.MetricValue AS varchar(100))) AS varchar(500)),
           CAST(REPLACE(R.Calculation, M.MetricID, 'CAST(' + CAST(M.MetricValue AS varchar(100)) + ' AS decimal(12,4))') AS varchar(500)),
           RN + 1
    FROM Replacements R
         JOIN #Metrics M ON PATINDEX('%' + M.MetricID + '%', R.Calculation) > 0
                        AND M.MetricDate = @Date
                        AND CHAR(RN + 96) = RIGHT(M.MetricID,1)
                        )
SELECT *
INTO #DSQL
FROM Replacements R
WHERE RN = (SELECT MAX(sq.RN) FROM Replacements sq WHERE sq.CalculationID = R.CalculationID);

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT 'UNION ALL' + CHAR(10) + 'SELECT ''' + CalculationID + ''' AS CalculationID, ''' + Calculation + ''' AS Calculation, ' + CastCalculation + ' AS CalculatedMetricValue' + CHAR(10)
                     FROM #DSQL
                     FOR XML PATH('')),1,10,'')

SELECT @SQL;

EXEC (@SQL);

DROP TABLE #DSQL;

GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE #Metrics;
DROP TABLE #Calculations;
```

*P.s. Yes, I know I didn't need the Temporary table #DSQL, I could just put the result from the CTE Replacements. The main reason was I split it out at that point so that I could separate the thought process, then I just didn't bother merging the two back together.*